# How can you verify a transaction details from a signature?

Tags: web3.js

Can anyone post a code example of how you can verify all the details of a transaction on the server from using just the signature, including NFTs in the transaction? Or is that much more difficult and you should only generate the transaction on the server and sign there before sending to the client?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot retrieve the transaction from just a signature. If that were possible, Solana could have massive transactions!

You'll need to either create it on the server side and sign it, or accept a signed transaction from the front-end and deserialize it on the server.